# Applying NAT only when routing to gateway

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn, nat

I have an OpenVPN server running behind a cable modem/router. I'm unable to add routes to this gateway. Connections to the server are good. I've attempted to setup internet routing through the VPN using the NAT Hack described at https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/NatHack. I've discovered that I lose the ability to connect to some of the physical network resources when attempting to route through a NAT.

Is there some command that will cause regular routing between the VPN and the physical network for all but connections through the gateway? How would IPtables and the OpenVPN configuration be setup?

The physical network is 192.168.x.0/24 with the gateway at 192.168.x.1. The VPN server manages a 172.16.x.0/24 network which forwards packets between the networks without filtering. Essentially, I'd like to apply NAT for packets going to the internet via 192.168.x.1 but make no changes for traffic between other hosts on 192.168.x.0/24 and 172.16.x.0/24.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the OpenVPN server’s firewall is trivial. Instead of just using `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` or `iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to <IP ADDRESS>`, you’d add another filter: Not destined for the local network, so something like `! -d 192.168.123.0/24`:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 ! -d 192.168.123.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

However, how would other devices know how to contact/send replies to the VPN network? You’d have to manually set up static routes on *all* devices. Because otherwise the traffic will be directed to the default gateway.

Keep in mind that routing is stateless. So even if a device receives a TCP connection from the VPN subnet, it will not know to respond via the OpenVPN server’s IP address. You must have an appropriate route somewhere.

Comment: I have the route on the VPN server. Its configuration pushes the route to the physical network to the VPN clients. As a general rule, I don't need devices on the physical network to initiate contact with the VPN machines. I have no problems, for example, connecting to the physical 192.168.x.y network printer from the 172.16.x.0/24 subnet as long as I don't use NAT.

Comment: ? A route on the VPN server applies only to the VPN server but no other device on the network. Unless the VPN server happens to be the default gateway on this network. // So did you try to augment the firewall rule as suggested? Did you encounter any problems with it?